# Defining Variables in Userform to be used in module

Tags: excel, vba

I create variables in a user form that I want to then reference in my module. I have tried labeling them as global, defining them on both the userform and module, on just the userform, on just the module, and a few other combinations but have not gotten it correct.

This is what I have as of now and by everything I have read should be correct:

*In declaration section of Userform:

```
 Dim ABC as Workbook
 Dim Primary as Workbook
```

---

*In a command button section of Userform

```
For j = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
    If ListBox1.List(j) Like "ABC" Then
        Set ABC = Workbooks(ListBox1.List(j))
        ABC.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
    If ListBox1.List(i) Like "Aggregate" Then
        Set Primary = Workbooks(ListBox1.List(i))
        Primary.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

*This continues for a few more variables, each indexed on a different letter.

In module, I then have something like this:

```
Primary.Sheets("Summary").Range("A5:H40").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
```

How do I define these workbooks (Primary, ABC, etc.) so that I can use them in my module, like the example above?

And when using in my module, can I just write `Primary.Sheets(.......)`

Or do I need to do `Workbooks("Primary").Sheets(....)`?

Maybe I should Dim Primary as String and go about it that way?

Comment: Define them as `Public` in your module. Then you can use them both in userform and in the module. `Public ABC as Workbook`

Comment: When I do that (define as public in just the module) I get "Object Variable or With Block Variable not set" on the line of code I listed above as coming from my module. Just as a reference, when I am calling in the Userform, I say Userform.Show and then perform those calculations, prior to doing those in the module. Is that the correct sequence? Maybe that is where the issue is?

Comment: or define them in a UserForm object and pass them to module as Sub's or Functions parameters

Comment: agree with @mehow: Are you calling the module procedure from Userform?

Comment: No, I am calling the Userform in from the module. I am defining variables through the userform, so the first line of the module calls in the userform (UserForm1.Show) in order to get/define the variables that will be used in the rest of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your normal module on the top (*below* `Option Explicit` *and above the first* Subroutine), add this code:

```
Public Primary As Workbook
Public ABC As Workbook

Sub Main()

    UserForm1.Show
    
    If Not ABC is Nothing Then
        ABC.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "activated ABC workbooks sheet 1"
    End If
    
    If Not Primary Is Nothing Then
        Primary.Sheets(1).Range("B1") = "activated primary workbook sheet 1"
    End If
    Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Declaring both `Primary` and `ABC` as *public workbook objects* allows you to access them anywhere in your VBA Project. This means they are accessible in Modules, Classes, and Userforms.

If you want to declare Public/Global variables you always have to use the regular Module objects not the Userform ones. They can only have private fields.

Now, your Userform1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim j As Long

    For j = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
        If ListBox1.List(j) Like "ABC" Then
            Set ABC = Workbooks(ListBox1.List(j))
            ABC.Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For j = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
        If ListBox1.List(j) Like "Aggregate" Then
            Set Primary = Workbooks(ListBox1.List(j))
            Primary.Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To prove the point you, once you've set your `ABC` and `Primary` workbooks, add a `Debug.Print ABC.Name` line to print out the Names. If nothing goes wrong then open the Immediate Window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and you will see the workbooks names printed out.

---

The other way around would be to send workbooks names through string parameters to a code module sub. You have to create a Sub in the code module taking workbooks names as String parameters. So, still in your UserForm1, add:

```
For j = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
    If ListBox1.List(j) Like "ABC" Then
        MySubInCodeModule Workbooks(ListBox1.List(j))
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

then in your code module, add:

```
Sub MySubInCodeModule(wbName As String)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks(wbName)
    
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "activate workbook: " & wb.Name
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("B1") = "active sheet: " & wb.ActiveSheet.Name

    'closing the active workbook
    wb.Close
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Last but not least, you can declare them publicly in the `UserForm` module, (it may be preferable to limit these variables' scope), and then reference them from the normal module/subroutine by qualifying:  `Debug.Print UserForm1.wb.Name` etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens I agree but this would only work if the form has been initialized.

Comment: Since OP is calling the form from the module, it seems likely that the UF will be initialized. OTOH, if the variables haven't been assigned, it makes no difference where you dimension them, but an object variable of `Nothing` can be handled easily enough either way. Just another option to consider, that's all.